# Python Numpy Reshape an array to (m,n) shape that has less than m*n elements

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am trying to convert a simple array into (m,n) shape but it has less than m*n elements.

My code:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
ary = np.array(list)
reary = ary.reshpae(2,3)
```

Present answer:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 5 into shape (2,3)
```

Expected answer:

```
reary = 

[[1,2,3],
 [4,5]]
```

Comment: you can't do jagged arrays, but you can use padding.

Comment: Numpy expects the items in your array to match the new shape you want to reshape to, therefore your approach does not work.

Comment: @PierreD what is padding?

Comment: Padding means to add for example a fixed numer of zeros to make up for the missing values. So in your case append a zero and then reshape. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html

Comment: As you can tell, your expected `reary` does not have a shape of (2,3)

Comment: @sehan2 this helps. I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
ary = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

r, c = 2, 3
a = np.pad(ary, (0, r * c - len(ary))).reshape(r, c)
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 0]])
```